# How do you get to have multiple root?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

So I am making an application in rails, and I require more than one roots like seen below

```
    root "post#index"
    root "gaming#index"
```

but it only allows me to have one root. Anyone have a solution?

Comment: why would you have more than one root??, you should be thinking of [`sub-domains`](http://railscasts.com/episodes/221-subdomains-in-rails-3)

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly you want to have different #root for different cases, in this case you could use `constraints`, or namespace your `#root`

Try it out, can be useful in your case. http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#advanced-constraints

Comment: what do I do when I want to link it? for example for root I do link to root_path

Comment: you could name this route http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#overriding-the-named-helpers

Answer (score 0):

The root of an application is the controller that will be activated when someone visits the root of your domain, e.g.

```
http://yourdomain.com/
```

you cannot have multiple places being pointed to from a root as there is only one url of that form.

As pointed out by bjhaid you can have multiple subdomains that are of the form:

```
http://sub1.yourdomain.com/
http://sub2.yourdomain.com/
```

but those are different, see [the rails routing guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html) for a description of the normal routing rules.